# Make a Unit Test E2E for Blazor Web App in .NET 8 Backend

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, tdd, e2e-testing, .net-8.0

How can make TDD for a Blazor Web App in .NET 8, how can test my backend API? Any idea how write E2E tests?

Thanks.

Comment: This is incredibly vague. Can you give more information and scope this to a more focused question please